# Android service call OnDestroy immediately when i start the service in sleep mode

Tags: android, service, wakelock, sleep-mode

I use a `BroadcastReceiver`To:

- Wake up the phone
- Playing sound and vibration in a service
- Show an `Activity`

Every things work well when i test it while the phone **is not** in `Sleep mode`

**BUT**

When the phone **is** in `Sleep mode` (phone is locked and the screen is off), the screen goes ON and the `Activity` is displayed well **but** Vibration Service goes to `OnDestroy` immediately after `onStartCommand`!

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class TimerTimeoutBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        WakeLockManager.acquireWakeLock(context);

        Intent closeDialogs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        context.sendBroadcast(closeDialogs);

        // Open OffAlarm Activity
        StartAlarmOffActivity(context);

        //StartVibrationService
        StartVibrationService(context);
    }

    private void StartAlarmOffActivity(Context context) {
        Intent alarmeActivity = new Intent(context, AlarmScreenOffActivity.class);
        alarmeActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(alarmeActivity);
    }

    private void StartVibrationService(Context context) {
        Intent playAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmSoundVibrationService.class);
        context.startService(playAlarm);
    }
}
```

In Vibration Service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent == null) {
        stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    play();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stop();


    WakeLockManager.releaseWakeLock();
}
```

In WakeLockManager:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE , "My Tag");
```

---

My questions:

- How can i prevent call `OnDestroy` Immediately when i start my service in sleep mode?
- Should i use a notification to keep this service alive?

---

**Edit 1**

I tried to take the service as a **foreground service** by a notification:

```
private void showNotification() {

    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.alarm_vibration_service_started);

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, AlarmScreenOffActivity.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    Notification notification = null;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

        notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)  // the status icon
                .setTicker(text)  // the status text
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())  // the time stamp
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.alarm_vibration_service_label)+" "+mTimerTitle)  // the label of the entry
                .setContentText(text)  // the contents of the entry
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)  // The intent to send when the entry is clicked
                .build();
    }

    // Send the notification.
    startForeground(Alarm_Vibration_SERVICE_Id,  notification);
}
```

Now i call `showNotification` in `onStartCommand` but it could not helped me!

**I'm success when** used i use a `Thread.Sleep(10000)` in onStartCommand **after `Play()`** and i have vibration on my phone for 10 second.

Codes:

```
private void play() {
    stop();
    mVibrator.vibrate(sVibratePattern, 0);

    enableTimeOut();

    mPlaying = true;
}

public void stop() {
    if (mPlaying) {
        mPlaying = false;
        mVibrator.cancel();
    }
    disableTimeOut();
}

private void enableTimeOut() {
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(
            mHandler.obtainMessage(TIMEOUT, true),
            1000 * ALARM_TIMEOUT_SECONDS);
}
```

---

Also i tested above codes in some cases. The result (Vibration for 10 seconds) was:

> - **Failed:**  Sleep-Mode  => An `Activity` with a countdown ----start----> `TimerTimeoutBroadcastReceiver`
> - **Failed:**  Sleep-Mode  => A `Service` ----start----> `TimerTimeoutBroadcastReceiver`
> - **Failed:**  Normal-Mode => A `Service` ----start----> `TimerTimeoutBroadcastReceiver`
> - **Success:** Normal-Mode => An `Activity` with a countdown ----start----> `TimerTimeoutBroadcastReceiver`

Finally I want start `TimerTimeoutBroadcastReceiver` from a `Service` in my APP but this problem confused me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved! Really my service (and also the notification) has worked correctly but i has this codes in `onPause` of the `Activity`:

```
protected void onPause() {
    Intent playAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmVibrationService.class);
    stopService(playAlarm);
    super.onPause();
}
```

It (`onPause`) happens right after my `Activity` opens in sleep-mode! I don't now why it happens but it cause stopping the service. Now i removed above code and the problem solved...